# Redundant entries with Doxygen

Tags: c++, namespaces, doxygen

I have a problem when generating the documentation of my source code with Doxygen. My code is written in C++.

Imagine you have a namespace defined in 'NNN.h', where you declared at some point different classes without detailing them:

```
namespace N
{
  class X;
  class Y;
  class Z;
};
```

Then, I defined properly those classes in 'X.cpp', 'X.h' and so on.

When generating my documentation with Doxygen, it generates two entries for class X/Y/Z. One of this entries belongs to namespace N, while the other is not. Besides, the second entry is almost empty (only the '\brief' field appears, no documentation for the methods/attributes).

How can I solve this problem ?